# PHP Nested Starcraft 2 Ladder Api

Tags: php, json, api

I want to make a personal profile page for my Starcraft 2 Clan with the API in PHP.

The normal stats are working for me.

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://eu.battle.net/api/sc2/profile/3077083/1/gbot/');
$obj = json_decode($json);

echo $obj->displayName;
```

However when I'll want to use the ladder stats I can't even display one variable.

```
$json = file_get_contents('
http://eu.battle.net/api/sc2/profile/3077083/1/gbot/ladders?locale=en_GB');
$lad = json_decode($json);
```

So how can I display the stats from the child with HOTS_SOLO in it?

Comment: Please add some data to understand which parts you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

This is just basic array access?

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://eu.battle.net/api/sc2/profile/3077083/1/gbot/ladders?locale=en_GB');
$data= json_decode($json);
$currentSeason = $data->currentSeason;

foreach ($currentSeason as $obj) {
    foreach ($obj->ladder as $ladder) {
        if ($ladder->matchMakingQueue == 'HOTS_SOLO') {
            // this is the ladder we want to display
            echo $ladder->ladderName; // Tychus Theta
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a newline in your URL (it starts on one line, where the whole literal begins on the line before). The file_get_contents() may be failing.

If that's not the problem, then it's something more subtle. Firefox/Chrome don't seem to have a problem with it. If json_decode is choking, it might be a forgiveable syntax issue. Try saving the data locally, and then removing components until it parses, and see if you can then do a string-replace or something to fix it, going forward.